# Dashboard quit working

Tags: kubernetes

K8s 1.5.4. I have a kubernetes cluster where the dashboard quit working. It was working for weeks but now does not display.

When I run `kubectl proxy` and navigate to
 `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard`

I get the following:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

When I run `kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system`:

```
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
heapster-v1.2.0-4088228293-j8gn5        2/2       Running   0          19d
kube-apiserver-96.118.29.200            1/1       Running   1          6d
kube-controller-manager-96.118.29.200   1/1       Running   29         20d
kube-dns-782804071-92kq8                4/4       Running   0          20d
kube-dns-autoscaler-2715466192-90jhm    1/1       Running   0          20d
kube-proxy-96.118.29.200                1/1       Running   22         20d
kube-proxy-96.118.29.213                1/1       Running   0          20d
kube-proxy-96.118.29.214                1/1       Running   0          20d
kube-proxy-96.118.29.217                1/1       Running   1          19d
kube-scheduler-96.118.29.200            1/1       Running   30         20d
kubernetes-dashboard-3543765157-7j40w   1/1       Running   0          20d
```

Running `kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-3543765157-7j40w --namespace=kube-system` hangs

Any ideas on how to diagnose?

Answer (score 1):

Check on which node this pod scheduled by running this:
`kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide` Next, ssh to that node and check hdd space is available: `df -h`

Also take a look here `kubectl describe pod -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-3543765157-7j40w`

And lastly try to delete the pod: `kubectl delete pod -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-3543765157-7j40w`
The scheduler will automatically recreate it and you'll be able to check logs for that new pod.